# Scp file with jsch gives 'unexpected filename'

Tags: java, scp, jsch

I'm using `Jsch 0.1.44` to scp a file from one host to another. The relevant code is the following:

```
public boolean transferFileToHost(File fileToTransfer, String destDirectory, String destFilename) {
    Channel channel = null;
    try {
        String command = "scp -t "+ destDirectory + destFilename;
        channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

        if(!connectToChannel(channel, in)) {
            return false; 
        }

        if(!sendScpCommand(fileToTransfer, command, out, in)) {
            return false;
        }

        if(!sendFileContent(out, fileToTransfer, in)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error while reading file. Error was: ",e);
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        logger.error("Error while sending ssh commands. Error was: ",e);
    } 
    finally {
        if(channel != null) {
            channel.disconnect();
        }
    }

private boolean sendScpCommand(File file, String command, OutputStream out, InputStream in) throws IOException {
    long filesize=file.length();
    command="C0644 "+filesize+" ";
    command+=file;
    command+="\n";

    out.write(command.getBytes());
    out.flush();
    if (checkAck(in) != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The command in this line

```
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
```

looks like this: `scp -t /tmp/config.xml` and the command in this line

```
out.write(command.getBytes());
```

looks like this: `C0644 5878 /home/myuser/config.xml`

The problem is, that I get the following error from scp: `scp: error: unexpected filename: /path/to/config.xml`

What is the reason for this error? How can I avoid it?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't the command need to be `scp /path/to/local/file server:path/to/remote/file`?  I have no idea what the `-t` option does.

Comment: scp -t executes a remote copy command. I've tooked it from the jsch examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. It seems that the source filename in the command must not contain any slashes. To solve this problem you simple have to change this line:

```
command+=file;
```

into this:

```
command+=file.getName();
```

Thats it.

Comment: Hey - Im using sharpssh which is a .net port of this library and i get the same error. I have a question about your solution - how do you supply a different path for the destination if you cant put slashes in the name?

Comment: @Karl the path does not matter here. See how you can change the path in my initial question above. The destDirectory is what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm lost. Can someone explain in baby speak what the problem and solution is? I'm using SSH.NET (a rework of SharpSSH).